# Does the symbol $(B \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}_p} V)^{G_K}$ mean the set of elements of $(B \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}_p} V)$ fixed by the Galois action of $G_K$?

Tags: hodge-theory, galois-representations

My question is rather symbolic meaning. In p-adic Hodge theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_Hodge_theory), it has been defined as follows: $$ D_B(V)=(B \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}_p} V)^{G_K}, \ \text{where $B$ is period ring and $G_K$ is Galois group. }$$ What does the symbol $(B \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}_p} V)^{G_K}$ mean?

Does it mean the set of elements of $B \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}_p} V$ fixed by the Galois action of $G_K$?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: @Mathmo123, thank you for help